# Poor performance in Python with Binary Read of files in a loop

Tags: python, performance

I'm iterating over the files in a folder and all subdirectories and then getting the hash of the file. Seems basic.

In this example, there are 1036 total files.  When I run this there will be 75,000 (or so) files

The code flies over the iterations as expected until we get into the late 900s in the file counter.

The issue is easy to isolate to the binary read.  Chunk size of the read (1024 vs 4096 vs 65536) does make a difference

If I run from the CMD line, the code executes the first 950 or so lines rapidly (~2 seconds) and then pauses on various files (not the same one all the time) and take about 20 seconds on avg to finish the file 75 files.

In PyCharm iterating over the 1036 files takes about 2:20 (seriously) on average

This code is pretty simple.  What's the issue?

(and please excuse the non-orthodox pythonic naming standards at this point)

```
import os
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime


def hash_file(filename):
    # make a hash object
    # the chance of a hash collision with sha1 or MD5 is minimal but I'm using sha256 because memory is plentiful
    h = hashlib.sha256()

    try:
        # open file for reading in binary mode - binary mode is a must
        with open(filename,'rb') as file:
            # loop till the end of the file
            fileChunk = None
            while fileChunk != b'':
                # read only 1024 bytes at a time
                #fileChunk = file.read(1024)
                # read only 4096 bytes at a time
                #fileChunk = file.read(4096)
                # read only 65536 bytes at a time
                fileChunk = file.read(65536)

                h.update(fileChunk)

        # the entire absolute path and file name
        print (os.path.realpath(file.name))
        # e.g exampe "/Users/testuser/PycharmProjects/test2/Examples/brianshirt_1.jpg"

        # return the hex representation of digest
        return h.hexdigest()

    except IOError as ioe:
        print("\n\nfile %s could not be opened" % filename)
        return "Error"

    finally:
        file.close()



startTime = datetime.now()
fileCounter = 0
#rootDir = '.'
rootDir = '/Users/testuser/Downloads'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)

    for fname in fileList:
        fileCounter += 1
        temp1 = str(fname) + ":" + str(hash_file(dirName+"/"+fname)) + " counter: " + str(fileCounter)


endTime = datetime.now()

totalTime = endTime - startTime
print ("Count of files hashed: " + str(fileCounter))
print ('Scanning Completed in: '+ str(totalTime))
```

Comment: and I have tried
replacing 
           while fileChunk != b'':
with
            while len(fileChunk) > 0:

Comment: Besides variable names being in camel case, your naming conventions seem quite standard. And even that seems to be a matter of taste, even though underscores are generally preferred.

Comment: Can you print out the size of each file you process in your debugging info?

Comment: You do not need the `finally` clause in `hash_file`. If there is an IO error, the file will not be opened and if the file is successfully opened, the context manager closes it...

Comment: Can you also show some sample output: A couple of lines from the start, a couple of lines where the slowdown happens, and a couple of lines from the end?

Comment: All good points but the big issue is why does the binary read performance go to crap?

Comment: The Java paralell to try-with-resources is `with`. There is no catch option in with, but the cleanup takes care of itself.

Comment: @MichaelGeiser. We're just offering advice to skirt around the fact that no one knows the actual answer :)

Comment: You can also do `for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(65536), b''): h.update(chunk)` instead of the while loop.

Comment: By the way, to make a more precise timing you might want to use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit),   your current measurement might be noisy

Comment: I'm going to look into other file readers but I have a hard time believing that the std file reader sucks that badly after all these years

Comment: timeit is kinda like the difference in Java between System.nanoTime() and System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: As far as the finally goes, I'd think explicitly closing the file would be good practice and would null . the object faster

Comment: I have tried your code on two directories. One has 882 files with 155MB and the other has 9672 files with 8.22 GB. The first took 0.35 seconds and the second took 0:00:21. No unusual pauses or unexpected slowness noted. Since `file.read()` is just a thin wrapper around the OS file read, your issue is likely OS related. You might try recompiling Python from source on your OS or making sure you have the most compatible version.

Comment: My guess is that the reads fill Windows disk cache and it starts getting more aggressive in swapping out pages. That puts interleaved writes on the same disk channel. How about monitoring the disk while the operation is in progress to see what happens? If you have more than one hard drive, make sure your data is not on the windows drive.

Comment: I'm on a 2017 MacBook Pro with an SSD with Python 3.6.4.

I'll try some of those ideas (updating to 3.7, etc) including running on a Win10 box tonight when I get home.

Comment: My test was on an iMac with a fusion drive. This is not a Python issue you are seeing. You are seeing some OS issue or install issue IMHO.

Comment: *As far as the finally goes, I'd think explicitly closing the file would be good practice and would null . the object faster*  The opposite is true. Since the `with` context manager will close the file automatically once the context block is exited (at the end of the `while` loop) the `finally` is always called on a already closed file object. And you are creating an unnecessary exception step (with additional execution time) to do what has either a) not been done (the IO error did not open the file) or b) already done (the exit from the context manager at the end of the `while` loop).